# jQuery AJAX form submit error working success not

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery

**EDIT**

Ok, so I can login fine but when I enter false info I'm redirected to the login page, what I need is to stay on the same page and show the error message `e.preventDefault();` doesn't seem to work.

```
   $(function() { 
    $("#login-form").submit(function(e) { 
        $('.fail').hide();
        $.ajax({  
            url:"/login",
            type: "post",  
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            error:function(){
                $('.fail').show();
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            success: function(){ 
                document.location = '/'; 
                }
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not actually doing anything with the form, ill try commenting your code to talk you through whats happening.

I'm guessing your using PHP server side for this code.

In PHP you want to check the user credentials and then tell the browser. If the login was successful send back `"y"`, and if it failed `"n"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
    $("#login-form").submit(function() { 
        $('.fail').hide();
        $.ajax({  
            url:"/login",
            type: "post",  
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            error:function(){
                $('.fail').show();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == "y") {
                   //Login was successful. Redirect statement here?
                } else {
                   //Failed login message here
                }
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
</script>
```

**Edit**

Try adding this in your success function. Please let me know what you get for a successful login and a failed login.

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

**Edit 2**

This is because your ajax call is successful, just that the login failed. This is why your success handler is called.

To sort this you'll need to see what is being returned from the server, is it nothing? In which case try:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data == "") {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        //Login successful, redirect user.
    }
}
```

Comment: @OliMillington Are you able to ask them to send back a "y" for successful login and "n" for failed? It will function in exactly the same way then

Comment: I can't contact the back end developers till Monday and I need to try and get this done today...

Comment: @OliMillington To help me answer can you try adding my edit in your code (see answer above)

Comment: I click the login button and nothing happens

Comment: Do you have firebug? Can you see anything in the console?

Comment: Ahh sorry... It show the html for the dashboard(logged in page)

Comment: @OliMillington Something is wrong with the backend there. It should only send a successful message back. I think youll need to speak to your backend developers about sorting that on Monday

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I'll upvote for your time. Much appreciated.

Comment: Back to the old dead button scenario... I give up for now, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
success: function(data){ 
   /* Validation data here, if authentication answer is correct */
   if(data == 'ok')
       document.location = '/'; 
   else 
      /* show error here */
}
```

Comment: this adds the username and password to the URL like "get", is there a "post" version?

Comment: You are using POST in your question? it shouldn't show in the url.

Comment: That's what I thought but when I tested your code it did a "get" style submit

Comment: `type: "post"`, what's problem?

Answer (score 0):

the success occur when URL is found and accessible.
and error occur when URL is not found.
if you want check the callback MSG you must print it in the URL page & check data in success.
like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
$("#login-form").submit(function() { 
    $('.fail').hide();
    $.ajax({  
        url:"/login",
        type: "post",  
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            if(data=="true"){
               alert("success");
            }else{
               alert("faild")
            }
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
});

</script>
```

in login.php

```
<?php
//check if for true...
echo "true";
//and if it is not true...
echo "false";
?>
```

the **data** parameter in **success** is a string which get back the html content of **"/login"**